# Find Four Pins of 50 in this Image! -- A Hidden Object Puzzle

Tags: visual, real

Tonight, my friends and I went to the mall. We planned to buy some shirts and pants, but suddenly... we found this!

These are number/size pins. They are typically used in hanger to denote the size of the clothes. We then decide to play some kind of *Hidden Object* puzzle, where we have to find at least a pin with a specified number, e.g. pin of 30.

Now it's your turn. Can you find **four pins of 50** in this image?

[image: find50]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think they are marked in red below:

> [image]

Finding them required

> using a roman numeral **L** for two of the fifties. Also, looking at the full-size image is pretty necessary to read at least one of the numerical fifties.

Also note that

> There are two more that *might* be fifty, which I put in blue rectangles.

Also,

> If that was cheating, someone else is free to point out the correct solution! :)

Comment: Curse the yellow circling, it took me the extra 41 seconds. :D

Comment: Curse the stupid arrows too.

Answer (score 8):

I found 4 pins:

> Two **50 pins**, and two **L pins** (which is 50 in roman numerals).
>  [Image with the pins circled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAjkw.jpg).

Comment: Man, I think I barely squeaked in ahead of you. Talk about a *photo finish*! :)

Comment: Upvoted for freehand circles.